# Plotly dash method to add google form

Tags: plotly

I am created a plotly dash.

i have added 3 dropdowns

dcc.Dropdown(

```
     id='FirstDropdown',
     options=[
            {'label':"1.view stats",'value':'v'},
            {'label':"2. view complete list",'value':'v1'},
            {'label':"3. G-form",'value':'v2'},
          ])
```

when the user selects the 3rd dropdown, i want to display a google form

Is it possible to add a google form there? How?

Comment: how is this question. different to one I already answered ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71368720/unable-to-add-google-form-in-plotly/71369344#71369344

Comment: @RobRaymond this question is identical to the one you answered.  This one was asked first without the rest of the code to make the app run.   The answer I posted below is identical to your answer for the code that was made available.  hari thought it would be better to tell me I'm wrong and start a new question with the rest of his code instead of working on the problem here.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to display a Google form as the conditional output of a dropdown by utilizing the html.Iframe() element.  You can find the necessary iFrame information for your Google Form under the Send menu.

[image: Google Send Form Menu For Embed HTML]

Below is a fully functional Dash application that will only display the Google Form if the third dropdown option is selected.

```
from dash import Dash, dcc, html, Input, Output

app = Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div(
    id='page-content',
    children=[
        html.H6("Display Google Form With Dash Callback"),
        dcc.Dropdown(
            id='FirstDropdown',
            options=[
                {'label': "1.view stats", 'value': 'v'},
                {'label': "2. view complete list", 'value': 'v1'},
                {'label': "3. G-form", 'value': 'v2'},
            ]
        ),
        html.Br(),
        html.Div(id='my-output'),
    ]
)


@app.callback(
    Output(component_id='my-output', component_property='children'),
    Input(component_id='FirstDropdown', component_property='value')
)
def update_output_div(input_value):
    if input_value == 'v2':
        google_form_iframe = html.Iframe(
            width='640px',
            height='947px',
            src="https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSfkIgHkKlD5Jl4ewfWpA8y9D65UbhdrvZ0k7qXOBI7uFN1aNA/viewform?embedded=true"
        )
        return google_form_iframe
    else:
        return f'Output: {input_value}'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Comment: no the code u shared throws this error in dash

Failed component prop type: Invalid component prop `figure` key `props` supplied to Graph.
Bad object: {
  "props": {
    "children": null,
    "height": "947px",
    "src": "https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLScdNtNMVIWqwddi3Q_1QvsP_qW-Pq8tamh4HzJphXYi-opwlQ/viewform?embedded=true",
    "width": "640px"
  },
  "type": "Iframe",
  "namespace": "dash_html_components"
}
Valid keys: [
  "data",
  "layout",
  "frames"
]

Comment: If you take the code above and put it in .py file by itself it will run without errors with dash 2.2.0  The error in your comment mentions a "figure" property and mentions a Graph object that doesn't exist in the sample code; therefore the error is occurring in your other code in that file.